# Downloading packages from Ubuntu local package mirror during Ubuntu 14.04LTS server installation

Tags: server, maas, apt-mirror, localrepository

During Ubuntu 14.04LTS server installation using MAAS, some packages are downloaded from Ubuntu mirrors.

Is there a way of installing Ubuntu using MAAS in an environment without internet connection i.e; instead of packages being downloaded from the internet, they are to be downloaded from a local mirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's should be pretty easy. There's a setting in MAAS for that.

Take a look at http://your-maas-server/MAAS/settings Ubuntu section. I guess „Main archive (required)“ field is just what you are looking for. (Of course I presume that you already have local mirror in your internal network).

I have an access to MAAS 2.0 at the moment, but 1.9 had the same setting too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the recenly installed packages in your local cache:

`/var/cache/apt/archive`

you can backup them from there in a directory and use

`dpkg -i PACKAGENAME.deb`

to install them.

Comment: Okay. But does that mean, if I create a package mirror on MAAS server the curtin installer will automatically download the packages from it rather than reaching out to the ubuntu mirrors?

Comment: To be honest, this is a question i dont know the answer to. And i cant try it out i not have the enviroment to test this. For sure you could initiate a manual install this way.